# R: Transition Matrix to Transition Probability Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, transition, probability

I have a transition matrix m:

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
             nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE,
             dimnames = list(c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"),
                             c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"))
             );
```

and would like a transition probability matrix that looks like this (adding up to 1.0 for each row).

```
0.00   0.00   1.00   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.00   0.50   0.50   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.33   0.00   0.33   0.33  0.00   0.00   0.00
...
```

Is there a standard function that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(m, 1)

          d1  d2        d3        d4        d5  d6        d7
d1 0.0000000 0.0 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d2 0.0000000 0.5 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d3 0.3333333 0.0 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d4 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0 0.0000000
d5 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 1.0000000
d6 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5 0.5000000
d7 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0 0.3333333
```

Here, the argument `1` means that the function is applied to each row separately.

Comment: Here the result: 
          d0  d1        d2        d3        d4  d5        d6
d0 0.0000000 0.0 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d1 0.0000000 0.5 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d2 0.3333333 0.0 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000
d3 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0 0.0000000
d4 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0 1.0000000
d5 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5 0.5000000
d6 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0 0.3333333  Do you know why some values are rounded and others are not ? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: @RalfB In you output, numbers have 7 digits following the dot at maximum. If the number can be displayed with less digits (e.g., `0.5`), it is displayed with less digits unless there are numbers in the same column with a higher number of digits. Note that all values in one column have the same number of digits.